# Create matlab table file from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matlab

I have a pandas dataframe that has 3 rows by 3 columns. The dataframe has the following form:

Input Dataframe:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | C1 |
| A2 | B2 | C2 |
| A3 | B3 | C3 |

I want to generate a .mat file from that dataframe and that when I open it in matlab it will be of the 3x3 table type, the same as the dataframe. I have tried the following code:

```
savemat('matlab.txt', {'df_name': df.to_records(index=False)})
```

When I do this, it generates the .mat file for me but it does not create a table in matlab, instead it creates a 1x3 structure and then takes the information.

How can I create a matlab file that when opened in matlab is a 3x3 table type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a pandas dataframe to a table from within MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57081181/how-to-convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-table-from-within-matlab)

Comment: No, because this answer is with matlab code. I need to make from pandas to matlab file with python. I'm using PyCharm not Matlab.

Comment: oh i'm sorry, it wasnt quite clear from the question. I think then that it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931576/converting-python-dataframe-to-matlab-file